# Reverse the odd indexed rows of a 2d array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, reverse

I want to reverse the odd indexed elements of the 2 dimensional array with single loop and without using conditional statement.

Input:

```
123
456
789
```

Output:

```
123
654
789
```

Here is my solution. But how can I achieve this without using Math.floor() and Math.abs() ?

```
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
  [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
];

let N = arr.length;
let M = arr[0].length;

for (let c = 0; c < N * M; c++) {
  let i = Math.floor(c / M);
  let j = c % M;
  let k = (Math.abs(i-1) % 2);
  let x = Math.abs(k * M - k - j);
  console.log(arr[i][x]);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to write an algorithm to do this, which you do not appear to have even attempted to do.

Comment: I attempted but I can't, that's why I posted in here

Comment: I see no evidence of you attempting anything.

Comment: I added. Check again.

Comment: This would appear to solve your original question, using a language you have not identified.

Comment: Remember to always [tag your question with the language you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) -- [tag:javascript] in this case. The language tag is the most important tag to use when asking questions; without it, the question is more difficult to find (for those answering & for future viewers).

Answer (score 0):

```
    const arr = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
  ];
  
  const n = arr.length;
  const m = arr[0].length;
  
  /*
   * 1 - left to right
   * 0 - right to left
   */
  const direction = 1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < n * m; i++) {
    const row = Math.floor(i / m);
    const col =
      ((row + direction) % 2) * (i % m) +
      ((row + 1 + direction) % 2) * (m - 1 - (i % m));
  
    console.log(arr[row][col]);
  }
```